# Only show field value if another field is equal to “X” VBA Acces

Tags: sql, vba, database, ms-access

Let's say I've got this query containing multiple tables.

[image]

Containing this data when run :

[image]

I want the query to show me the data exactly as it is in the database but when I run my SQL statement it'll show it as if on the second row the field OpslagLocatie has the same data as the field above it.

Outcome :

[image]

My solution :

```
    Me.[Keuzelijst EAN artikel op vooraad].RowSource = 
"SELECT TussenMAATenARTKEL.EAN_Code AS [EAN Code], TbOpzoekKleur.Kleur AS Kleur, TbOpzoekVoorraadMaat.VoorraadMaten AS Maat, Sum(Stock.Aantal_per_Lokatie) AS Aantal, TbOpzoekVoorraadLocatie.VoorraadLocatie AS Lokatie, Stock.ArtikelDetail_ID AS Detail, IIf([TussenMAATenARTKEL].[Opslaglocatie], [Stock].[VoorraadLocatie_ID]=8,[TussenMAATenARTKEL].[OpslagLocatie]) AS [Opslag Locatie]  " & _

     "FROM (TbOpzoekVoorraadMaat RIGHT JOIN (TbOpzoekKleur RIGHT JOIN TussenMAATenARTKEL ON TbOpzoekKleur.ColorCode = TussenMAATenARTKEL.Colorcode) ON TbOpzoekVoorraadMaat.VoorraadNummer = TussenMAATenARTKEL.VoorraadNummer) RIGHT JOIN (TbOpzoekVoorraadLocatie RIGHT JOIN Stock ON TbOpzoekVoorraadLocatie.VoorraadLocatie_ID = Stock.VoorraadLocatie_ID) ON TussenMAATenARTKEL.ArtikelDetail_ID = Stock.ArtikelDetail_ID  " & _

     "GROUP BY TussenMAATenARTKEL.EAN_Code, TbOpzoekKleur.Kleur, TbOpzoekVoorraadMaat.VoorraadMaten, TbOpzoekVoorraadLocatie.VoorraadLocatie, Stock.ArtikelDetail_ID, Stock.VoorraadLocatie_ID, TussenMAATenARTKEL.Artikel_ID, TussenMAATenARTKEL.OpslagLocatie  " & _


    "HAVING (((Sum(Stock.Aantal_per_Lokatie)) <> 0) And ((TussenMAATenARTKEL.Artikel_ID) = " & test & ")) " & _
                                                    "ORDER BY TbOpzoekVoorraadMaat.VoorraadMaten;"
```

Outcome after updating my code with an iif statement :

[image]

After running my code the field TussenMAATenARTKEL.OpslagLocatie only shows the values -1 or 0. I expect it to show or not show the OpslagLocatie instead of -1 and 0.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please use https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ to provide sample data and expected result. Also try to simplify the problem as much as possible - e.g. remove all columns that are not relevant to the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Can you help me little bit more : Is your IIF command set properly = IIf(expr, truepart, falsepart) ?

Comment: I think my IIF is set correctly, it's "IIf([TussenMAATenARTKEL].[Opslaglocatie], [Stock].[VoorraadLocatie_ID]=8,[TussenMAATenARTKEL].[OpslagLocatie]) AS [Opslag Locatie]"

Answer (score 0):

That's because your *OpslagLocatie* is a lookup field.

So, in your query, join and include the table and the field in this from where *OpslagLocatie* looks up the code KBA-ACC.

Comment: How would I do that in my current statement?

Comment: We don't have your table design, so paste your current SQL into the query designer, add the lookup table and, when done, adjust your code to generate similar SQL.

Comment: No matter what I try, it wont stop displaying a -1 or 0 or OpslagLocatie on rows it's not supposed to.

Comment: Well, without other info than "it doesn't work", no one can help you.